# Ouput PostgreSQL query into INT powershell variable

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I am quite new in using Powershell and try to output the result of a PostgreSQL query into a Powershell variable in order to use as a trigger for sending emails.

The returned value is a numeric value = 1 but it is considered as a system.Object and thus not recognised as INT.

See my code below (all email related code removed, no issue on that part)

```
# QUERY FOR EMAIL TRIGGER
Set-Location "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v4\runtime\"; 
$sql_trigger = $(.\psql -h $Server -p $DBPort -U $User -d $Database -w -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -c "select trigger_value from my_table ;" -t)
$trigger = $sql_trigger


Write-Host "trigger is "$trigger


[int]$_trig_false = 0
[int]$_trig_true = 1 

IF ($trigger -as [int] -eq $_trig_false) {
Write-Host "Trigger value is 0 and will trigger an ERROR email"
    }

ELSEIF ($trigger -as [int] -eq $_trig_true) {
write-host "Trigger value is 1 and will send email with file attached"
    }

ELSE {
Write-Host "TRIGGER NOT READY"
#exit
    }
```

here is the result.

```
trigger is               1 
TRIGGER NOT READY
```

Many thanks in advance for the support

Comment: `$sql_trigger` is probably an _array_ of strings, try `$trigger = $(@($sql_trigger) -match '\d' |Select -First 1) -as [int]` instead of `$trigger = $sql_trigger`.

Comment: thank you, it fixes the issues